# Can not fetch to get local json data file?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch to get local json data file in VScode, but no success, I tried everything! :((

Can anyone help me please?
[image]

Comment: const path = require('path')
fetch(path.join(__dirname, './test.json'))

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` is used for requests to the web server.

You can import it directly if you are not running a web server:

```
import * as testContent from './test.json';
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't use `fetch` to read a local JSON file; instead, you use the `readFile()` method as demonstrated below:

```
const { readFile } = require("fs/promises");

async function readJsonFile(filename) {
  const data = await readFile(filename, "utf8");
  const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
  console.log(parsedData);
}

readJsonFile("./test.json");
```